# && means: AND, || means OR

Tags: javascript

Is there a way through some sort of meta or pre-processor to tell JavaScript that the word AND equates to && and the word OR equates to || and <> equates to !===?

Maybe equate THEN to {

END to }

NOT to !

Comment: Are you talking about actual code written with infix notation?  Like you have "if (a and b) { }" in code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Don't do it.

... well, there is a way, but don't do it anyways...

Here it is....

```
function loadScriptWithReplacements(url) {
     try {
          var rq = null;
          if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
               rq = new XMLHttpRequest();
          else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
               try {
                    rq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
               } catch(o) {
                    rq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
               }
          }
          rq.open("GET", url, false);
          rq.send(null);
          document.write('<script>' + rq.responseText.replace(/(and|or|\<\>)/g, function(r) {
               return {
                    'and': '&&',
                    'or' : '||',
                    '<>' : '!=='
               }[r];
          }) + '</script>');
     } catch(ex) {
          // We can't have a fallback because you're using invalid JavaScript :(
          throw new Error("Could not use Ajax.");
     }
}
```

But, DO NOT DO THAT! You could also perform the replacements server-side, but DON'T DO THAT EITHER!

Doing it server-side increases the strain on your server, doing something that could be avoided by just remembering how to write JavaScript correctly.

Comment: minitech, this is interesting - and I can understand what's going on here.  How would I call loadScriptWithReplacements?

Comment: @cf_PhillinSenn: Anywhere you would normally link to the script. But really, don't do it - people that don't have Ajax browsers (I suppose there are very few, though) would be left out, and it just is bad coding practice.

Comment: There's a nice way around the ajax problem.  If you declare a script tag with an unknown type, it won't process it.  <script type="my_javascript"> for instance.  Then you can iterate over those dom elements, fix the syntax, remove the attrib, and you are good to go.

Comment: @user535759: The problem there is that this is built to link to an external script.

Answer (score 3):

Coffescript uses a [rewriter](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/documentation/docs/rewriter.html) to provide syntactic sugar.  http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

From the section titled "If, Else, Unless, and Conditional Assignment"
The coffeescript

```
if happy and knowsIt
  clapsHands()
  chaChaCha()
else
  showIt()
```

is rewritten to

```
if (happy && knowsIt) {
  clapsHands();
  chaChaCha();
} else {
  showIt();
}
```

Comment: @tylermwashburn, the function names are not mine.  They're from the coffee script docs.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do that. Well, theoretically, it could be done, but it would be slow and or difficult. Is there a good reason to use AND in place of && and OR in place of || ?

I suppose you could pre-process your code using awk,sed,perl,python,bash,[insert favrotie scripting language], but why?